# How can I run a java.class from Main Activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm a beginner at Android Development and hoping someone can help me a bit out.

I want to connect to a local server (IP). I found a code in GitHub that supposedly would do this connection. But the thing is that this is a `java.class` and not in my `MainActivity`. So when I run my app in the emulator now, nothing happens. How can I run the `Java.class` from inside my `MainActivity`?

Here is the source: https://github.com/calimero-project/introduction/tree/master/src/main/java

Class:

```
public class CreateTunnelingLink
{

    /**
     * Local endpoint, replace the IP address with your actual address. The local socket address is important for
     * multi-homed clients (several network interfaces), or if the address via InetAddress.getLocalHost is not useful.
     */
    private static final InetSocketAddress local = new InetSocketAddress("192.168.10.13", 3671);

    /**
     * Specifies the KNXnet/IP server to access the KNX network, insert your server's actual host name or IP address,
     * e.g., "192.168.1.20". The default port is where most servers listen on for new connection requests.
     */
    private static final InetSocketAddress server = new InetSocketAddress("myKnxServer.myHome",
            KNXnetIPConnection.DEFAULT_PORT);

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("This example establishes a tunneling connection to the KNXnet/IP server " + server);

        // A KNX tunneling link supports NAT (Network Address Translation) if required.
        // We also indicate that the KNX installation uses twisted-pair (TP) medium, with TP1 being the most common.
        // KNXNetworkLink is the base interface implemented by all supported Calimero links to a KNX network.
        try (KNXNetworkLink knxLink = KNXNetworkLinkIP.newTunnelingLink(local, server, false, TPSettings.TP1)) {
            System.out.println("Connection established to server " + knxLink.getName());
            System.out.println("Close connection again");
        }
        catch (KNXException | InterruptedException e) {
            // KNXException: all Calimero-specific checked exceptions are subtypes of KNXException

            // InterruptedException: longer tasks that might block are interruptible, e.g., connection procedures. In
            // such case, an instance of InterruptedException is thrown.
            // If a task got interrupted, Calimero will clean up its internal state and resources accordingly.
            // Any deviation of such behavior, e.g., where not feasible, is documented in the Calimero API.

            System.out.println("Error creating KNXnet/IP tunneling link: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you include the code for the java class and your main activity?

Comment: I have added my code, I haven't done something in my MainActivity because I don't know what I should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final InetSocketAddress local = new InetSocketAddress("192.168.10.13", 3671);
    private static final InetSocketAddress server = new InetSocketAddress("myKnxServer.myHome",
            KNXnetIPConnection.DEFAULT_PORT);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // call your method to do the task
        yourMethodForMakingConnection();
    }

// for better separation you can create a method for this task
private void yourMethodForMakingConnection() {
        System.out.println("This example establishes a tunneling connection to the KNXnet/IP server " + server);

        // A KNX tunneling link supports NAT (Network Address Translation) if required.
        // We also indicate that the KNX installation uses twisted-pair (TP) medium, with TP1 being the most common.
        // KNXNetworkLink is the base interface implemented by all supported Calimero links to a KNX network.
        try (KNXNetworkLink knxLink = KNXNetworkLinkIP.newTunnelingLink(local, server, false, TPSettings.TP1)) {
            System.out.println("Connection established to server " + knxLink.getName());
            System.out.println("Close connection again");
        }
        catch (KNXException | InterruptedException e) {
            // KNXException: all Calimero-specific checked exceptions are subtypes of KNXException

            // InterruptedException: longer tasks that might block are interruptible, e.g., connection procedures. In
            // such case, an instance of InterruptedException is thrown.
            // If a task got interrupted, Calimero will clean up its internal state and resources accordingly.
            // Any deviation of such behavior, e.g., where not feasible, is documented in the Calimero API.

            System.out.println("Error creating KNXnet/IP tunneling link: " + e);
        }
}


}
```

This should work if the code is correct. Think of the `onCreate` function of your `Activities` as the main function. You don't need another class for a task that small.

Or else, you can otherwise also just create an instance of that class inside your `onCreate` method in the `MainActivity` and just call the `main` method that establishes the connection from that class with the object.

Either way, you'll be able to do it.

You can learn more about the basics of [Android Development](https://developer.android.com/guide), [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity), and [Android Activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) so that you can understand this better.

Comment: Hi, now I could run my app, so I think this works. But I get an error: `I/System.out: Error creating KNXnet/IP tunneling link: tuwien.auto.calimero.KNXException: connecting from /192.168.10.118:3671 to /192.168.10.13:3671: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)`. Maybe I did something wrong with the IP adresses. I know the server is 192.168.10.13:3671 and the PC is 192.168.10.118, but maybe the port is wrong?

Comment: Try uninstalling the app completely from your device and then install again, make sure you also have Internet permissions in your manifest file, if not, add these two: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Comment: I've tried it, and I have those two in my Manifest. I get this error know, it's not the same as last. `: connecting from /192.168.10.118:3671 to /192.168.10.13:3671: bind failed: EADDRNOTAVAIL (Cannot assign requested address)`.

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer, because that's was my question in the first place.

Comment: This line `private static final InetSocketAddress local = new InetSocketAddress("192.168.10.118", 3671);` When I change this IP to my local on the emulator it crashes, but if I use any IP except that the app don't crash, but it won't connect either. Could it be a emulator problem?

Comment: I'm sorry but these errors are more specific to the code you're using and I'm not aware of it. You can better query these issues in the GitHub thread from where you got the code. Someone who knows it would be able to better help you. Anyway, if the efforts were helpful for you an upvote will be highly appreciated :)

Comment: Yes, You did answer my question :) Can I ask for a code example for if I want to have a seperate class but call it in `OnCreate`?

Comment: I think just creating a normal `object` of another class inside the `onCreate` block and then using that object to make a dot call to the method would work. I hope you already know how to create new objects of a class ;)

Comment: I will figure it out, thank you for your help ;)

Comment: One thing, I've learned that I have to use a dedicated thread like Async for this to work on Android. Is there a simple way to manage that in this code?

Comment: Yes you can't make network calls on main thread. You can use libraries like Retrofit to handle things for you but still you'll have to learn how to harness the code a bit, so there's no escape!

Comment: do you know how I can get the `local` and the `server` from a preference screen and not dynamic like in the code I posted?